# UnsatisfiedDependencyException with Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

I just started [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) tutorial and it **works** fine. (Spring Boot)

Then I decided to go a step further and implement a Observer and Observable. The observableIml has a List with all observers listening to the Observable.

My goal was that I can store the ObservableImpl. with its list in the database.

For that I actually really copied & pasted the code from the tutorial. I hardly changed anything, and nothing due to dependencies. But suddenly Intellij complains with a **UnsatisfiedDependencyException**

Here is my code:

**HibernateApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HibernateApplication {


    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HibernateApplication.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(CustomerRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {
            // worked fine, now continue with addObservables implementation
            // useCustomerRep(repository);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner addObservables(ObservableRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {
            useObserver(repository);

            // fetch all customers
            log.info("Observables found with findAll():");
            log.info("-------------------------------");
            for (ObservableImpl customer : repository.findAll()) {
                log.info(customer.toString());
            }
            log.info("");

        };
    }

    private void useObserver(ObservableRepository customerRepository) {
        ObservableImpl observable = new ObservableImpl("1");
        observable.addObserver(new ObserverImpl("firstObserver"));
        observable.addObserver(new ObserverImpl("secondObserver"));
        observable.addObserver(new ObserverImpl("thirdObserver"));
        customerRepository.save(observable);
    }

    private void useCustomerRep(CustomerRepository repository) {
        // save a couple of customers
        save(repository);
        System.out.println(repository.count());

        // fetch all customers
        log.info("Customers found with findAll():");
        log.info("-------------------------------");
        for (HibernateCustomer customer : repository.findAll()) {
            log.info(customer.toString());
        }
        log.info("");

        // fetch an individual customer by ID
        HibernateCustomer customer = repository.findOne(1L);
        log.info("Customer found with findOne(1L):");
        log.info("--------------------------------");
        log.info(customer.toString());
        log.info("");

        // fetch customers by last name
        log.info("Customer found with findByLastName('Bauer'):");
        log.info("--------------------------------------------");
        for (HibernateCustomer bauer : repository.findByLastName("Bauer")) {
            log.info(bauer.toString());
        }
        log.info("");
    }

    private void save(CustomerRepository repository) {
        repository.save(new HibernateCustomer("Jack", "Bauer"));
        repository.save(new HibernateCustomer("Chloe", "O'Brian"));
        repository.save(new HibernateCustomer("Kim", "Bauer"));
        repository.save(new HibernateCustomer("David", "Palmer"));
        repository.save(new HibernateCustomer("Michelle", "Dessler"));
    }
}
```

**ObserverRepository**

```
public interface ObservableRepository extends CrudRepository<ObservableImpl, Long> {
}
```

**ObservableImpl**

```
    @Entity
@Data
public class ObservableImpl extends Observable {

    private static AtomicInteger idGenerator = new AtomicInteger();
    @Id
    private final int ID;
    private final String name;
    @OneToOne
    private final List<Observer> observerList = new LinkedList<>();

    public ObservableImpl(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ID = idGenerator.getAndIncrement();
    }

    public ObservableImpl() {
        this.ID = idGenerator.getAndIncrement();
        name = "none";
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void addObserver(Observer o) {
        super.addObserver(o);
        observerList.add(o);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void deleteObserver(Observer o) {
        super.deleteObserver(o);
        observerList.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ObservableImpl that = (ObservableImpl) o;

        return ID == that.ID;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return ID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ObservableImpl{" +
                "ID=" + ID +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**ObserverImpl**

```
@Entity
public class ObserverImpl implements Observer {


    private static AtomicInteger idGenerator = new AtomicInteger();
    @Id
    private final int ID;
    private final String name;

    public ObserverImpl(String name) {
        this.ID = idGenerator.getAndIncrement();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ObserverImpl() {
        this.ID = idGenerator.getAndIncrement();
        name = "none";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ObserverImpl{" +
                "ID=" + ID +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ObserverImpl observer = (ObserverImpl) o;

        return ID == observer.ID;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return ID;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {

    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

**Error Message**

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.3.RELEASE)

2017-06-10 14:40:02.052  INFO 22184 --- [           main] c.e.Hibernate.HibernateApplication       : Starting HibernateApplication on DESKTOP-JN403B9 with PID 22184 (C:\Dropbox\Projects\h2TestEnv\target\classes started by Gaming in C:\Dropbox\Projects\h2TestEnv)
2017-06-10 14:40:02.053  INFO 22184 --- [           main] c.e.Hibernate.HibernateApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-06-10 14:40:02.076  INFO 22184 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4516af24: startup date [Sat Jun 10 14:40:02 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-10 14:40:02.774  INFO 22184 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cabbaf72] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-06-10 14:40:02.970  INFO 22184 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-06-10 14:40:02.976  INFO 22184 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-06-10 14:40:02.977  INFO 22184 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
2017-06-10 14:40:03.031  INFO 22184 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-06-10 14:40:03.031  INFO 22184 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 956 ms
2017-06-10 14:40:03.117  INFO 22184 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-06-10 14:40:03.119  INFO 22184 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-10 14:40:03.119  INFO 22184 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-10 14:40:03.119  INFO 22184 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-10 14:40:03.119  INFO 22184 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-10 14:40:03.327  INFO 22184 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-10 14:40:03.334  INFO 22184 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-06-10 14:40:03.366  INFO 22184 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-06-10 14:40:03.367  INFO 22184 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-06-10 14:40:03.367  INFO 22184 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-06-10 14:40:03.387  INFO 22184 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-06-10 14:40:03.437  INFO 22184 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2017-06-10 14:40:03.679  INFO 22184 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2017-06-10 14:40:03.704  INFO 22184 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-10 14:40:03.771  WARN 22184 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addObservables' defined in com.example.Hibernate.HibernateApplication: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'addObservables' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'observerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.Obs.ObservableImpl
2017-06-10 14:40:03.771  INFO 22184 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-10 14:40:03.774  INFO 22184 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-06-10 14:40:03.780  INFO 22184 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-06-10 14:40:03.785 ERROR 22184 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'addObservables' defined in com.example.Hibernate.HibernateApplication: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'addObservables' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'observerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.Obs.ObservableImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.Hibernate.HibernateApplication.main(HibernateApplication.java:27) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'observerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.Obs.ObservableImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.Obs.ObservableImpl
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:68) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:153) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:199) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can you please explain to me what I am doing wrong here and how I can fix that?

Thank you very much.

Here my repo: https://github.com/realsony/h2TestEnv

Comment: Have you used 'ComponentScan' annotation on 'HibernateApplication' class??? Also '@EntityScan' ???

Comment: No. It wasn't annotated in the tutorial and it worked without these. I just tried it with and it is still not working.

Comment: Okay, can you add basePackages to the annotation and try?

Comment: I added now @ComponentScan({"com.example.Obs","com.example.Hibernate"}) to the HibernateApplication.java is that as you wish? But still it is not working

Comment: Can you add EntityScan as well, am seeing Entity classes? What is t working? Have you got the same error?

Comment: I did, yes. I updated my question with a picture. And yes, i still have the same error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146325/discussion-between-annaklein-and-harshavmb).

Comment: Am not seeing packages in EntityScan annotation. It won't scan anything if you don't specify packages of entity classes

Comment: Revert both the annotations as SpringBootApplication has ComponentScan in it. Looks like something else

Comment: @AnnaKlein Use `@EnableJPARepositories` annoatation

Comment: At the HibernateApplication class? I did, nothing changed :(

Comment: I think the problem is, that you extend java.util.Observable but didn't anotade it with @Entity. I could be wrong. But if I am right maybe someone else can help you with my idea (it's to difficult for me to solve)

Comment: every java object extends Objects which you also never annotade with @Entity ?

Comment: The problem is that you're putting "com.example.Obs" with capital 'O' and your package is "com.example.obs". The problem is that it's not finding this package, because it doesn't exists.

Comment: The ComponentScan was a suggestion by harshavmb what didn't work. (I still tried it with lowercase btw and it didn't worked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spring Boot configuration works this way:

**@SpringBootApplication** maps the beans and components from the packages starting from the current package. Example:

If you have the packages:

```
com.example
com.example.obs
```

And your @SpringBootApplication is in ***com.example*** package, it will map all the subpackages. But, you have this:

```
com.example.hibernate
com.example.obs
```

If you just rename the package to com.example it will work (in this project you'll have problems with wrong hibernate mapping, but the configuration it will work).

Theorically, @ComponentScan should solve these issues, but maybe because of the organization of the project and multiple configurations (HibernateApplication/DemoApplication) it isn't.

By the way, when you do that, let the ***com.example*** package only with the configuration files.

Edit: But, if you want to work this way, you should do this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.example")
@EntityScan(basePackages="com.example")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example")
public class HibernateApplication { ... }
```

Comment: Indeed. Moving the classes all into the same package worked now. I tried several ways to make it working like I had it. ComponentScan (thats btw included in springBoot) with @Component annotation at the other classes. EntityScan etc. Nothing worked. Have you another idea how it worked with that: com.example.hibernate
com.example.obs

Comment: See my edit... Basically you should add the paths that should be on Spring Boot's management...